# How to avoid ImageGenerator fills pixel points to outside area of image boundary?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, image-augmentation

I am using `ImageGenerator` function of `tf2.4` to augment plant images, however, the generated images were filled by pixel points for the outside image boundary, which regards to its modes `{"constant", "nearest", "reflect" or "wrap"}` of `ImageGenerator`, which is not needed in my case. Regarding [`ImageGenerator` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), there is no option to disable those modes.

Sample of the generated image that I got with `ImageGenerator` and given parameters.

Code:

```
generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(vertical_flip=45)
data = generator.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir, target_size=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), color_mode='rgb',
    class_mode='sparse', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    shuffle=True,
    save_to_dir=OUTPUT_DIR, 
    save_prefix='augmented', 
    save_format='png',
    follow_links=False, 
    subset=None, 
    interpolation='nearest'
)
```

Result:

[image]

The inside area of the red drawing line is what I mentioned about filling pixel points to the outside of the image boundary.

I'm curious to know if there are any options for solving my aim?

Comment: what do you want instead?

Comment: @NicolasGervais I want augmentation by just rotation without additional pixel points.

Comment: But you can't have an octogon-shaped picture. So what do you want as the missing pixels?

Comment: I want to keep the original image but  rotated

Comment: How did you rotate the image? `vertical_flip` takes a boolean value

Comment: Not using flip, I used `rotation_range`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.